# Disarming certain macros when saving a copy of a workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have set up a macro that creates and saves a copy of an original workbook. However I do not want certain macros from the original to run on the copy. Is there some way that I can get the macro, that creates and saves a copy of the original, to 'disarm' certain macros?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is dependent upon the workbook design.  First, are the macros tied to buttons?  If yes, then they can be removed from the buttons, or the buttons could be deleted.  If not, there is no direct way to 'disarm' macros as you put it.  One trick that comes to mind however is to make the macros you want to disable dependent on the name of the workbook (assuming the saved workbook is under a different name).  Then, the macros can be set to run only under the original workbook name using if statements.

Comment: The macros are not tied to buttons so using the IF statement sounds like what I want to do. I'm just not sure how I would do that?

Comment: If not thisworkbook.name = "your primary workbook.xlsm" then exit sub  ***This will end the sub you don't want to run if you place it as the first line of the sub.  You can use this on any sub you don't want to run.  I have tested this and it does work.

Comment: My Formula is like this now:

Comment: Sub Auto_Open()
If Not thisworbook.Name = "Proposal.xlsm" Then Exit Sub
Range("BI1") = Range("BI1") + 1
End Sub

Comment: my apologies for not being clearer before.  This should take care of the object error.  *Note* spelling and case matter here so make sure you have the names exact.

Comment: `Sub Auto_Open()`  
        `Dim nameString As String`  
        `nameString = ThisWorkbook.Name`  
        `If Not nameString = "Proposal.xlsm" Then Exit Sub`   
        `Range("BI1") = Range("BI1") + 1`   
    `End Sub`

Comment: +++ That's awesome. I have got it going!

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [VBIDE object library](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBE.aspx)

disclaimer: carefully read the *"Introduction"* and its ***CAUTION*** clause

then add your project the needed reference to *Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3.* and code as follows:

```
Sub DeleteModule(wb As Workbook, moduleName As String)
    With wb.VBProject
        .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(moduleName)
    End With
End Sub
```

to be called by your main sub as follows

```
Sub main()

    ' ... code to get to the original workbook saved copy
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\...\FileTest.xlsm"

    DeleteModule ActiveWorkbook, "ModuleNameToDelete" '<--| this will erase the wanted module from the active workbook (i.e. the just "savedas" workbook)

    '... more code

End Sub
```